# in sql server how to get a column values with `<br>` separate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In sql server how can I get a column's values with `<br>` separating them?

Here I am getting with comma separated, but how can I get `<br/>` in html in sql server?

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ',' + cast(Citation_Id as nvarchar(500))
    FROM tollplus.violated_trips
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) As CitationId
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `Citation_Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    STUFF(
             (SELECT
                  '<br/>' + cast(Citation_Id as nvarchar(500))
                  FROM tollplus.violated_trips
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.','varchar(max)')
             ,1,5, ''
         ) AS Citation_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `<br />` appearing as `&lt;br /&gt;`

```
SELECT  (     
        SELECT CASE
                 WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) = 1 THEN ''
                 ELSE '<br />'
               END + cast(Citation_Id as nvarchar(500))
        FROM   tollplus.violated_trips
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')  As CitationId
```

Although actually if `CitationId` itself does not contain any problematic characters the following may be more performant if the estimated costs in the execution plan can be believed.

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(
    (
        SELECT CASE
                 WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) = 1 THEN ''
                 ELSE ','
               END + CAST(Citation_Id AS NVARCHAR(500))
        FROM   violated_trips
        FOR XML PATH('')  
    ), ',', '<br />'
  ) AS CitationId
```

[image: Execution Plan]